# Current location in MapFragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hello can you please help me how to achieve to get Current location in a google maps fragment?

I am using `NavigationDrawer` in my application and I display map as Fragment.

But I cannot find the solution to show current location of user.

here is code of my fragment: I included only few methods.

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
  View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map1);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
  return v;
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}





@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    map = googleMap;

}
```

I am able to set current location to normal `MapView` but not in fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to give your application [This Permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)

Then you need to have the device's current location:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
```

Now you have your coordinates (longitude , latitude), Then instantiate LatLng object:

```
LatLng yourLocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
```

And now move camera to your current location:

```
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(yourLocation, 13));
```

First argument is the destination and 13 is the zoom level

Any question ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, now i am getting : cannot resolve method getSystemService. I am doing this in MapFragment class under onMapReady.

Comment: You are welcome, I see, I will change the line, take a look please, how about now?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have been doing this the same way before with the same outcome. It works now! cheers!

Comment: I did, but i have less than 15 reputation so i can not upvote it.

Comment: accepting an answer does not need reputation bro. take a look at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png)